# To create custom the wordpress template with both the static and dynamic mixed

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am trying to customize the wordpress template. 
In that template the content will be both static and dynamic.
Images, color and button will be static.
All other content will be dynamic.

What I am trying to do is that if i change button name or color in that template it should affect is all place in the sites.
I know about the the_content() I don't know whether split will work.
But is their any to do this process in the form of template.
[For Example see the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co04m.png)
Please need help.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for having dynamic content on your website you can use custom fields..

you can either use the Wordpress built in custom fields or a very good plugin Advanced custom fields (ACF) ..

explanation can be lengthy but you can refer to below documentation and actually it is very simple..

https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields ( For WP built in Custom fields)
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/ ( for ACF plugin )

Hope this helps

Take care and happy coding

Comment: Thank you. But Now I have added the image in my question. That I want to bring that layout.In that layout the button will pop up with some message.only first title is dynamic. mostly some will be static in all pages.Background color and/or image will same in all pages.I will have 100 pages like that.

Comment: Sorry Sara I do not understand this entirely

Comment: Normally if we want to pull the content we will put `<div class="some classes"><?php the_content(); ?></div>`. For my scenario what i want to do is In this title and description should be pulled out from the database.button click with popup the form. button name,background color and/or image are same in all pages that we should like a static thing.

Comment: for eg: `<div style="background:#333;"><h4>title from the db</h4><div class="col-xs-8">description from the database</div><div class="col-xs-4">form is static</div></div><div style="background-image:url();"><h4>title2 from the database</h4><div class="col-xs-12">description from the db</div><input type="button" name="enquire"  value="[contact-form-7 id="95" title="form"]"/></div></div>` So background image,button name,form If I change it. I want Change in one single template it should reflect in all place where the template is used.Description & title want to come from the db.Note:db-database

Comment: if the content is what is stored in contact form 7 then you will have to check its documentation.But if this is a part of the db which was stored in any other way then you can use $wpdb ( check its documentation on wordpress.org) and use SQL queries on it.once you are able to retrieve the content then adding it to a button should not be difficult

Answer (score 0):

If you just want your first title dynamic, then you can fetch data title from your page like with

```
the_title();
```

And all your remaining data will be static in this way you can get your layout easily ... as far as your button pop up message concerned, you can use jQuery to achieve that and can show any of your message. Hope that solves your issue